# How would I implement forwarding of a website that's in a subfolder?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, website, forwarding

User has been given a subfolder to hold their website at http://www.example.com/user. If possible, I'd like to forward that off to userdomain.com, as that's a different server and I have control over that. If it's not possible of course I'd like to know that too. I vaguely recall being able to do something like that, but I don't remember any specifics.

If it helps example.com is running IIS, an user domain.com will be running apache. It would be an added bonus if the url shown in the browser was still example.com/user, but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple redirect would probably be a more performant solution but if you want the URL to remain example.com/user you could use a reverse proxy.

http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisreverseproxy/index.html